# Boostrap bug? trying to reach 15 characters

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, file

This code works without bootstrap, but with bootstrap it displays the file input tag.
Help

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.nodisplay
{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<input type="file" class="nodisplay">
<div class="nodisplay">lol</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the `!important` modifier to make your code overwrite the bootstrap code. This should work:

```
.nodisplay
{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work as the input type file is given

```
 .nodisplay, input[type='file']
{
  display:none;
}
```

in the bootstrap.css

```
input[type='file'] {
  display:block;
}
```